# Looking for good books on Immutable Infrastructure

Tags: immutable-servers

I am looking for the best books on Immutable Infrastructure. I am interested in books on theory and application. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on what you're most interested in? The question as it is currently posed makes it a bit difficult to come up with a relevant answer, I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am willing to bet that this answer may not age well, I would suggest

["Infrastructure as Code"](https://infrastructure-as-code.com/) by Kief Morris for the "theory" part.

For the "application" part, I would suggest ["Terraform up and Running"](https://www.terraformupandrunning.com/) by By Yevgeniy Brikman.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I am specifically interested in bare metal Immutable as well. Hopefully 'Terraform Up and Running' it's not public cloud centric.

Comment: I got those books and I am blown away. Especially Kief's book. I am looking for good reference projects that really illustrate good organization and process and use of current tooling as well...